# Codeigniter post data from declared variable

Tags: sql, json, database, api, codeigniter

```
function index_post() {
        $sql = "SELECT id_so FROM so_detail ORDER BY id_so DESC LIMIT 1";
        $last_id2 = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
         foreach ($last_id2 as $row) {
             $last_id = $row->id_so;
         }
         //echo $last_id;
         $data = array(
                'id_so'      => $this->post($last_id),
                'id_product' => $this->post('id_product'),
                'harga'      => $this->post('harga'),
                'harga_dasar'=> $this->post('harga'),
                'modal'      => $this->post('modal'),
                'pajak'      => $this->post('pajak'),
                'qty'        => $this->post('qty'),
                'keterangan' => $this->post('keterangan'),
                'create_user'=> $this->post('create_user'),
                'create_time'=> $this->post('create_time'),
                'update_user'=> $this->post('create_user'),
                'update_time'=> $this->post('create_time'));
         $insert = $this->db->insert('so_detail', $data);

        if ($insert) {
            $this->response($data, 200);
        } else {
            $this->response(array('status' => 'fail', 502));
        }

    }
```

i got a problem that the posted id_so is "null". when i echo $last_id it show correct id ex: 120. but when i call it to $this->post($last_id), it just be null..

How to post id_so with a string that already declared before ($last_id) ??

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Why are you using $this->post()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many array in $last_id2 variable.data will insert multiple time based on your last_id2.try this:

```
foreach ($last_id2 as $row) {
 $data = array(
                'id_so'      =>$row->id_so,
                'id_product' => $this->post('id_product'),
                'harga'      => $this->post('harga'),
                'harga_dasar'=> $this->post('harga'),
                'modal'      => $this->post('modal'),
                'pajak'      => $this->post('pajak'),
                'qty'        => $this->post('qty'),
                'keterangan' => $this->post('keterangan'),
                'create_user'=> $this->post('create_user'),
                'create_time'=> $this->post('create_time'),
                'update_user'=> $this->post('create_user'),
                'update_time'=> $this->post('create_time'));
         }
 $this->db->insert_batch('so_detail',$data);
```